# Modificar Excel en Python

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7

Estoy trabajando con un xlsx que tiene esta data:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

necesito realizar una division entre las celdas D y C de esta manera:
D/C
y que cada valor se coloque en las celdas de la columna E:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esta forma, solo me queda que excel me filtre los valores de la columna Fillrate mayores a 0.1 con sus respectivos valores de las demas columnas y me devuelva algo asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Soy nuevo con las librerias de Excel para python y solo se abrir el archivo y escribir str en alguna celda por lo tanto necesito si alguien me pueda escribir el codigo de estos 3 pasos. Gracias

Dejo el enlace del xlsx: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0L1ZT-zXzKlX2dfOXo5LXhtM2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Usa pandas, cargado el excel con [pandas.read_excel](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.read_excel.html) crear la nueva columna es trivial: `df[Fillrate] = df["Ad Impressions"]  / df["Market opportunities"]`, luego solo tienes que hacer un fitro boleano `df = df[df["Fillrate"] > 0.1]` y por último guardas el dataframe en un Excel usando [pandas.DataFrame.to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html). Inténtalo y si te encuentras con problemas agrega el código y el problema concreto que tienes.

Comment: Lo solucione desde un csv y no creando un xslx! Gracias